# How can I make Firefox load AngularJS normally?

Tags: angularjs, firefox, webtorrent

I have an AngularJS app which works fine in Chrome but when using Firefox it takes a few seconds before it renders it as it should. Firefox shows the {{variables}} and everything inside ng-hides for a few seconds.

The website is http://diegorbaquero.com/bTorrent/ and it works completely fine in Chrome, but Firefox has this delay.

Thank you

Comment: I assume [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) is what you are looking for?

Comment: As mentioned by @Evilzebra, add `ng-cloak` directive as attribute to the element where you have put `ng-app`

Comment: @Evilzebra Yes! That worked! Didn't know it existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i use `ng-bind` and `ng-cloak` to overcome the problem of {{variables}}.

In my case i use `ng-bind` for href tag.

```
<a href="#/faqs/{{faq.name}}" ng-bind="faq.name"></a>
```

and ng-cloak for li

```
<li ng-if='current_user'><a ng-href="#/profile" class="ng-cloak">{{current_user.first_name}}}}&nbsp{{current_user.last_name}}</a></li>
```

Comment: I used ng-clock in the whole controller but it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to hide your app until after Angular loads.

Answer (score 0):

**1:** You can use **ng-cloak**. Include this in your css:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
    display: none;
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-cloak>{{name}}</div>
```

2: Or, You can use **ngbind**

```
<div  ng-bind="name"></div>
```